# How to modify copy/paste on Ubuntu-terminal to Windows-WSL-like?

Tags: 22.04, windows, gnome-terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, copy-and-paste

On the one hand, [I like the way that WSL+Bash handles copy/paste. Ctrl+C only copies when something is selected. If nothing is selected then Ctrl+C behaves as usual and sends a SIGINT.](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/968#issuecomment-495935319)
On the other hand, in Ubuntu-gnome-terminal, I have to use `ctrl shift c`/`v` to copy/paste inside the terminal, while outside the terminal, `ctrl c`/`v` works. Is there any way to modify this behavior to make it Windows-WSL-like? I mean, can we have a unified behavior that only allows `copy`/`paste` when certain conditions are met, regardless of whether I am inside or outside the terminal?

PS: I know there is some workaround that uses re-mapping and changing `SIGINI` to other keys. I just wonder whether we can achieve such *smart* behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the shortcut in the terminal just like you are using it outside, you can achieve this by changing your shortcuts in your `gnome-terminal`.

- First, open your Gnome-terminal through All apps or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
- Click on the three lines over the top right corner of your terminal. Then click on **Preferences**.
- Then on the new windows, select shortcuts and change the shortcut for **Copy/Paste** from <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>C/V</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C/V</kbd>.

[image: terminal-preferences]

Comment: Wow, it was partly solved! However, according to my practice, I found such settings work for the vscode terminal since it has trigger conditions. While in gnome-terminal, such setting breaks the normal `ctrl c` `SIGINI`...